# How to use COLLATE in a JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, collation

I´m trying to join two tables but I get this error:

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 8 
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

```
SELECT *

  FROM [FAEB].[dbo].[ExportaComisiones] AS f

  JOIN [zCredifiel].[dbo].[optPerson] AS p

  ON (p.vTreasuryId = f.RFC) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: Move the `COLLATE ...` after the column of which you want to change the collation, i.e. **inside** the parenthesis (or leave them completely, they're not needed here).

Answer (score 3):

You need to `collate` one column not both :

```
SELECT f.*, p.*
FROM [FAEB].[dbo].[ExportaComisiones] AS f JOIN 
     [zCredifiel].[dbo].[optPerson] AS p
     ON p.vTreasuryId COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = f.RFC;
```

I don't know which column needs to change collation name but this will guid you how to explicit change the collation name.

However, if the two column has same collation name then you don't need to change collation.